# Is there any way to create peer to peer TensorFlow environment?

Tags: tensorflow, p2p

Currently they provides distributed tensorflow environment : 
https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed

Is there any ways to create this environment using peer to peer network if we know which node(ip addres) we connect?